# avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding: lilypad arduino

Tags: serial, programmer

i realise this is probably the most common error that is asked about on this forum, but it is a major issue for me. i have an arduino lilypad main board (with the ATMega328P, boot loader already burned), and a generic FTDI serial to usb adapter plugged into my windows 10 laptop. When i try to upload the Blink program from the Arduino IDE, it fails with the error:

`avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe`

i am using a windows 10 laptop, the Arduino IDE from the windows store. this is a new lilypad, and i have never been able to upload to it. take note that when i reset the board, the pin13 light does flash (but  not the way the Blink program specifies, obviously.

i have already tried:

- Rebooting my computer
- Restarting the IDE
- Turning the COM port on and off
- Taking out the RX/TX wires from the FTDI converter
- Pressing the reset button right before uploading (or during uploading)
- Changing which board it is set as in the IDE
- Unplugging and re-plugging the USB-Serial converter

[image: my wiring, the USB end goes in to the laptop of course]

if you have any other possible solutions they would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: 1) does the board have a bootloader? 2)the programmer setting is ignored if you use serial upload 3) add a photo of the wiring

Comment: it does have the boot loader already, I will add a photo of the wiring tomorrow (GMT+10)

Comment: Sorry, probably irrelevant in this case, but AVRISP MKII is the enabled option in the IDE programmers section

Comment: what is "Taking out the RX/TX wires from the Lilypad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I bought one of the Lilypads, it did not have a bootloader. I had to buy a SMD programmer adapter that presses down over the 328P chip to bootload it as the board did not break out the ICSP pins to any pads.  [image]

I think I got mine here https://hobbyking.com/en_us/atmel-atmega-socket-firmware-flashing-tool.html but I haven't seen them in stock for a while.  Very handy tool tho. Another option is to tack wires to the appropriate uC pins and, connected to a 2x3 header that your Programmer can connect to. Remove the wires when done.

Comment: Thanks, how can I confirm if my Lilypad has a bootloader?

Comment: In the IDE, in File:Preferences, turn on Verbose outputs.  Press and hold reset, then start a download. When you see "Compiled xxx of 32,xxx bytes", release reset. You will see the down load attempted three times. It may take a few tries to get the timing right. If you can't ever get it working, then you probably don't have a bootloader.

Comment: the 2x3 points are for the ICSP header

Comment: Yes, I see the picture now. Add 2x3 male pins, and plug on a Programmer and put a Bootloader on the '328P.